Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} \cdot \sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2})$
How can I show that the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} \cdot \sqrt{2})$ is contained in the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} + \sqrt{2})$?
I need to show that $\sqrt[3]{5} \cdot \sqrt{2}$ can be written as a linear combination of elements in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} + \sqrt{2})$.
The closest I got was:
Call $u = \sqrt[3]{5}$ and $v = \sqrt{2}$.
We have: $(u+v)^3 = u^3 + 3u^2v + 3uv^2 + v^3 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2})$
But $u^3 = 5$, $v^2 = 2$, and $v^3 = 2v$, so
$
3u^2v + 6u + 2v \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2})
$
Rearranging, we have:
$
3u(uv) + 4u + 2(u+v) \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2}) \implies 3u(uv) + 4u \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2})
$
But I still need to show that $u \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2})$, so I hit a dead end.
Edit: my original problem was to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt{2}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} + \sqrt{2})$.
The degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt{2})$ is 6. The minimum polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{5} \cdot \sqrt{2}$ is $x^6 - 200$, meaning $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} \cdot \sqrt{2})$ has also degree 6.
The idea was to show that if
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} \cdot \sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} + \sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt{2})$
then, due to the degrees, they must be equal.
Is this the best way to do it? I have been struggling with it for a long time now.

I'm not sure it helps, but note that $\sqrt[3]5 \cdot \sqrt 2 = \sqrt[6]{200}$.

Consider $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt{2})$, this is a 6-dimensional linear space on $\mathbb{Q}$. So as to find the minimum polynomial of $u + v$.

$u + v$ is a root of the degree 6 polynomial $x
^6 −6x^4−10x^3+12x^2- 60x+17$, but how do I check for its irreducibility? I think it's easier to work with $x^6-200$.

I think proving $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} ) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} \sqrt{2} )$ is easier combined with the equality of degree of both of them.
Let $u=\sqrt[3]{5}, v=\sqrt{2}$, we want to prove $u+v \in  \mathbb{Q}(uv) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} \sqrt{2}) $.
$u+v= \frac{1}{20}(2(uv)^{3}+(uv)^{4}) \in \mathbb{Q}(uv)$.
Your goal is proving $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} ) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} \sqrt{2} )$ and the argument above is enough for it.
Note: If you want to prove $  \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} \sqrt{2})\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} )$, then it's just matter of calculation, so it's not big deal.
Edit:
To prove $f(x)=x^{6}-6x^4-10x^3+12x^2-60x+17$ is irreducible, you can use mod$(19)$ test:
First:
$f(x) mod (19)$ has the same degree as $f(x)$ and don't have any roots in $Z_{19}$.
Second:
Prove that all irreducible second degree and third degree polynomials in $Z_{19}[x]$ don't divide $f(x) mod(19)$.
Third: When you have done with these calculations, you reach that is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Important note:
I tried mod$(p)$ test for all primes less than $19$, but didn't work because our function is reducible over them, so in fact you just need to explore different reducibility tests and mathematical programs that can help you with the nasty calculations.
I used:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=17+-+60+x+%2B+12+x%5E2+-+10+x%5E3+-+6+x%5E4+%2B+x%5E6+over+finite+field+of+19+elements
(If you want, you can use Mathematica for such calculations)
See the following link:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IrreduciblePolynomialQ.html

Yes, you proved $\mathbb{Q}(u+v) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} \sqrt{2})$, but the question is the other way around.

@aschepler He edited the question in its body, see the end part of body of the question

I know that [$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}$] = 6.
It is straightforward that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt2) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt2)$.
So the problem would amount to showing that [$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt2): \mathbb{Q}]$ = 6.
To this end, I must show that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt2$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ has degree 6.

The polynomial of degree 6 that has $\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt2$ as a root is $m:= x^6 \text{-} 6x^4 \text{-} 10x^3+12x^2\text{-}60x+17$. But, to know if that's the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt2$, I should show that this polynomial is irreducible, right? If I cannot do this a priori, I cannot guarantee that [$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt2): \mathbb{Q}]$ = 6.

The idea of proving $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}\cdot \sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} + \sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt{2})$ was to deal with the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{5}\cdot \sqrt{2}$, which is $x^6-200$.
When you switch the problem to proving $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt2) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}\cdot \sqrt{2})$, it seems that the problem goes back to its original difficulty. Am I wrong?

@lkksn I will  try to prove it is irreducible and edit

@lkksn I have edited it

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If you want to prove$  \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} \sqrt{2})\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} )$, then:
Let $u= \sqrt[3]{5},v=\sqrt{2}$.
$M_{1}=u+v \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2}$
In the following $M{i}$ I am removing rational part.
$(u+v)^{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} )$ implies $M_{2}=2uv+u^{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} )$
$(u+v)^{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} )$ implies $M_{3}=3u^{2}v+6u+2v \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} )$
$(u+v)^{4} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} )$ implies $M_{4}=8uv+12u^{2}+5u+20v \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} )$
$(u+v)^{5} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} )$ implies $M_{5}=20u^{2}v+25uv+5u^{2}+20u+4v \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} )$
$(u+v)^{6} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} )$ implies $M_{6}=30u^{2}v+24uv+60u^{2}+150u+200v \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+ \sqrt{2} )$
We want to solve:
$x_{1}M_{1}+x_{2}M_{2}+x_{3}M_{3}+x_{4}M_{4}+x_{5}M_{5}+x_{6}M_{6}=uv$, where $x_{i} \in \mathbb{Q}$.
This lead to the following  equation:
$(x_{1}+0x_{2}+6x_{3}+5x_{4}+20x_{5}+150x_{6})u+(0x_{1}+x_{2}+0x_{3}+12x_{4}+5x_{5}+60x_{6})u^{2}+(x_{1}+0x_{2}+2x_{3}+20x_{4}+4x_{5}+200x_{6})v+(0x_{1}+2x_{2}+0x_{3}+8x_{4}+25x_{5}+24x_{6})uv+(0x_{1}+0x_{2}+3x_{3}+0x_{4}+20x_{5}+30x_{6})u^{2}v=uv$
Which leads to the system:
$(x_{1}+0x_{2}+6x_{3}+5x_{4}+20x_{5}+150x_{6})=0$
$(0x_{1}+x_{2}+0x_{3}+12x_{4}+5x_{5}+60x_{6})=0$
$(x_{1}+0x_{2}+2x_{3}+20x_{4}+4x_{5}+200x_{6})=0$
$(0x_{1}+2x_{2}+0x_{3}+8x_{4}+25x_{5}+24x_{6})=1$
$(0x_{1}+0x_{2}+3x_{3}+0x_{4}+20x_{5}+30x_{6})=0$
The solution for this system is in the following link:
https://matrixcalc.org/slu.html#solve-using-Gaussian-elimination%28%7B%7B1,0,6,5,20,150,0%7D,%7B0,1,0,12,5,60,0%7D,%7B1,0,2,20,4,200,0%7D,%7B0,2,0,8,25,24,1%7D,%7B0,0,3,0,20,30,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,0%7D%7D%29
